# SymPy dsolve couldn't solve for initial conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

I am trying to solve the following differential equation with ics using SymPy's `dsolve`:

[image: diff eqn with ics]

```
from sympy import Function, Derivative, dsolve, symbols
t, k = symbols('t,k', real=True)

M = Function('M')(t)
M_ = Derivative(M,t)
Eqn = M_ - k*M
sol = dsolve(Eqn, ics={M.subs(t,0): 100, M.subs(t, 6): 97})
```

I get the following error:

```
File "..\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\sympy\solvers\ode\ode.py", line 826, in solve_ics
    raise ValueError("Couldn't solve for initial conditions")
ValueError: Couldn't solve for initial conditions
```

For some reason, SymPy is struggelig to solve this equation, which can easily be solved by hand.

Comment: Your initial conditions are inconsistent with the ODE. You have two ICS but this is only a 1st order ODE. Do you mean that you want to solve for k?

Comment: @oscar Both are required to determine both the integration constant and the constant k. However, you are absolutely right. I need to solve firstly using dsolve for one of the ics, and thereupon using solve with the second ics, with k as unknown. Perfect, thanks! On the other hand, it would have been nice if dsolve understood this by itself, or somehow I could give it a hint.

Comment: The way `dsolve` sees it is that only the functions like `M(t)` are unknowns. The symbol `k` is a parameter rather than an unknown. The problem as you have presented it to sympy is one that has no solution for almost all possible values of `k`.

Comment: One could probably just add `dk/dt=0`, making `k(t)` a (constant) function, as a second equation to the system, then you have two equations and two value conditions.

Answer (score 1):

As Oscar pointed out, dsolve failed to solve the ODE, because only one initial condition was required. However, both conditions are required in order to 1) solve the ODE and 2) determine the parameter k. Which must be done separately. The following code accomplishes this:

```
from sympy import Function, Derivative, dsolve, solve, symbols, Eq
t, k = symbols('t,k', real=True)

t1 = 0
M1 = 100
t2 = 6
M2 = 97

M = Function('M')(t)
M_ = Derivative(M,t)
Eqn = Eq(M_,k*M)
sol = dsolve(Eqn, ics={M.subs(t,t1): M1})

expr = sol.rhs.subs(t,t2)
eqn2 = Eq(expr,M2)
k_value = float(solve(eqn2,k)[-1])
sol_with_k = sol.subs(k,k_value)
print(sol_with_k)
```

Which gives the correct output:

```
Eq(M(t), 100*exp(-0.00507653458078476*t))
```